# How to fill an Ext.form.CheckboxGroup with checkboxes generated based on a JSON object returned from a server

Tags: javascript, json, extjs

I'm trying to dynamically fill an `Ext.form.CheckboxGroup` with `Ext.form.Checkbox`s derived from a JSON object pulled from a jsp page. My JSON object looks like this:

```
{
    "sensors": [ 
        { "id": 200, "name": "name - B - A" }, 
        { "id": 201, "name": "name - B - B" }, 
        { "id": 202, "name": "name - C - A" }, 
        { "id": 203, "name": "name - C - B" } 
    ]
}
```

I can load these objects into an `Ext.data.JsonStore` with code like this:

```
new Ext.data.JsonStore({
    id: 'sensorStore',
    autoLoad: true,
    method: 'GET',
    baseParams: {
        jobType: 'sensor'
    },
    url: 'getstatus.jsp',
    root: 'sensors',
    sortInfo: { field: 'id', direction: 'ASC' },
    fields: [ 'id', 'name' ]
}),
```

My understanding is that this will give me access to a set of `Ext.data.Record` objects, but I can't figure out how to go about iterating through those Records to create any `Ext.form.Checkbox`s, or if there's some other way of achieving the same result.

I'm not trying to set the values of the checkboxes, though I will need to be able to reference them when I submit the form.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming the store is loaded (since you have autoLoad:true), you need to

1. iterate through the records to create an array of checkbox configs
2. create the checkboxgroup object (using the array created in #1 above as items config)
3. add this checkboxgroup to your form (or whatever container) and call this container's doLayout() if it is already rendered

Snippet to iterate and create checkbox configs-

```
var checkboxconfigs = []; //array of about to be checkboxes.   
mystore.getRange().each(function(record){
    checkboxconfigs.push({ //pushing into array
        id:record.data.id,
        boxLabel:record.data.name,
        //any other checkbox properties, layout related or whatever
    });
});
```

Snippet to create checkboxgroup-

```
var myCheckboxgroup = new Ext.form.CheckboxGroup({
    id:'myGroup',
    fieldLabel: 'Checkboxes in two columns',
    columns:2,
    items:checkboxconfigs //created in previous snippet.
    //any other checkbox group configuration
});
```

Add to your container and redraw it-

```
mycontainer.add(myCheckboxgroup).doLayout();
```

EDIT - Your JsonStore config does not match to the data returned. (id needs to be an int)

```
new Ext.data.JsonStore({
    id: 'sensorStore',
    autoLoad: true,
    method: 'GET',
    baseParams: {
        jobType: 'sensor'
    },
    url: 'getstatus.jsp',
    root: 'sensors',
    sortInfo: { field: 'id', direction: 'ASC' },
    fields: [ {name:'id', type:int}, 'name' ]
}),
```

Comment: This looks like it's what I need. I've been able to get it almost working, but have a question. Is loading the JsonStore asynchronous? When I run this code, and console.log() the results, my .getRange() call is empty. If I check the value of the .getRange() call later, using my Chrome Developer Tool Console, it shows data. If the call to load the Store is asynchronous, how do I make sure the data's loaded before beginning the iteration through the Records?

Comment: I've figured the asynchronous part out, and put all of the above snippets in a callback from my JsonStore.load() call. Now I'm getting an "Uncaught TypeError: Object 200 has no method 'indexOf'". (Here "200" is the id of the first Object that should be a CheckBox in my group.) I have no idea what this means.

Comment: edited my answer above - In your JsonStore - fields: [ {name:'id', type:int}, 'name' ]

Comment: Thanks! It's all working now. I did have to use forEach instead of each in myStore.getRange().forEach(function(record), though I'm not sure why.

Comment: I also had to use forEach instead of each